# C++ / MFC multiple inheritance calling base class constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am getting **error C2512: 'derived' : no appropriate default constructor available** error in both the constructor definitions of the **derived** classes. My code is like the following. How can I solve this issue?

```
Class A
{
    int a, int b;
    A(int x, int y)
    {
        sme code....
    }
}

Class B
{
    int a, int b, int c;
    B(int x, int y, int Z)
    {
        sme code....
    }
}


Class derived : public A, public B
{
    derived(int a, int b):A(a, b)
    {

    }

    derived(int a, int b, int c):B(a, b, c)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Try making the constructors public. Also, you have to initialize your inherited copy of A *and* B somehow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error C2512: no appropriate default constructor available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689319/error-c2512-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available)

Answer (score 5):

One of the problems is that in each of your derived classes' constructor you are forwarding the appropriate constructor arguments to only one of your two base classes. None of them has a default constructor, so you need to explicitly provide arguments for the construction of both base classes `A` and `B`.

The second problem is that the constructors of your base classes are implicitly declared as `private`, so the base class cannot access them. You should make them either `public` or at least `protected`.

Minor problems: after a class definition, you need to put a semicolon. Also, the keyword for declaring a class is `class`, not `Class`.

```
class A // <---- Use the "class" keyword
{
public: // <---- Make the constructor accessible to derived classes
     int a, int b; 
     A(int x, int y) 
     { 
         some code.... 
     } 
}; // <---- Don't forget the semicolon

class B // <---- Use the "class" keyword
{
public: // <---- Make the constructor accessible to derived classes
    int a, int b, int c;
    B(int x, int y, int Z)
    {
        sme code....
    }
}; // <---- Don't forget the semicolon


// Use the "class" keyword
class derived : public A, public B
{
    derived(int a, int b) : A(a, b), B(a, b, 0) // <---- for instance
    {

    }

    derived(int a, int b, int c) : B(a, b, c), A(a, b) // <---- for instance
    {

    }
};  // <---- Don't forget the semicolon
```

Answer (score 1):

Both class A and B don't have default constructor, you need to initialize A and B constructor explicitly in derived constructor. You failed to initialize A or B constructor in each derived constructor:

```
derived(int a, int b):A(a, b), B(a, b, 0) 
                               ^^^
{
}

derived(int a, int b, int c):A(a, b), B(a, b, c)
                             ^^^
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first derived ctor calls A's ctor but not B's ctor, so the compiler tries to call B's default constructor, which does not exists.

Same thing for the second derived ctor, but switch A and B.

Solution: Specify default ctors for A and B.