# Error C2512 No appropriate default constructor even though I have one?

Tags: c++, constructor, tree

Solved by added a default constructor to the symbol struct, but also I would like to ask why there is a call to a default constructor if possible. If not, it's fine. thanks.

I'm trying to write a tree, but when I define a node like so:

```
TreeNode<SymbolPriority>* treeRoot =
    new TreeNode<SymbolPriority>(SymbolPriority('a', 1));
```

I can't compile and it throws an `Error c2512 'SymbolPriority': no default appropriate default constructor`; however, in my struct I have the constructor I am trying to use, and I have used it before, so I do not know what is going on.

I have tried this:

```
SymbolPriority aSymbol( 'a', 1 );

TreeNode<SymbolPriority>* treeRoot = new TreeNode<SymbolPriority> (aSymbol);
```

but it doesn't work either.

I put down the relevant code below:

```
template<typename DATA_TYPE> struct TreeNode
{
TreeNode(const DATA_TYPE& value, TreeNode* left = NULL, TreeNode* right = NULL)
{
  Value = value;
  Left = left;
  Right = right;
}

DATA_TYPE Value;
TreeNode* Left;
TreeNode* Right;

bool IsLeaf() const
{
  return Left == NULL && Right == NULL;
}

};
```

and

```
struct SymbolPriority
{
   SymbolPriority(char aSymbol, int priority){
       Symbol = aSymbol;
       Priority = priority;
   };

   char Symbol;
   int Priority;

   bool operator > (const SymbolPriority& compareTo) const{
        return (Priority > compareTo.Priority );
   };

   bool operator < (const SymbolPriority& compareTo) const{
    return !( *this > compareTo);
   };

   bool operator==(const SymbolPriority& compareTo) const{
        return (Priority == compareTo.Priority );
   };

};
```

Comment: Neither of those classes have a default constructor. Also, your `operator<` is actually `operator<=`.

Comment: TreeNode<SymbolPriority>* treeRoot =  new TreeNode(SymbolPriority('a', 1 ) );

Try this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default constructors are used to initialize objects without use of arguments.
To fix this, simply put:

```
TreeNode() { // NO PARAMETERS
    ... // default initializing variables, or whatever you'd like
}
```

In your structures, classes, and any others if they are declared without arguments.

In case you'd like to hear more on the concept of ["Default Constructors"](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr376.htm).

---

There are quite a few stackoverflow questions relating to **Error: C2512**.
Consider looking at this:
[error C2512: no appropriate default constructor available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689319/error-c2512-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available)

---

*Wikipedia* happens to give a great explanation on the necessity of default constructors [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor).

Some notable purposes are:

- "*When an array of objects is declared, e.g. MyClass x[10];; or allocated dynamically, e.g. new MyClass [10]; the default constructor is used to initialize all the elements*"
- "*When an object value is declared with no argument list, e.g. MyClass x;; or allocated dynamically with no argument list, e.g. new MyClass or new MyClass(); the default constructor is used to initialize the object*"
- "*When a derived class constructor does not explicitly call the base class constructor in its initializer list, the default constructor for the base class is called*"

That last one is important for inheritance.

Comment: I considered that, but constructing the symbol outside of the instantiation doesn't work either (did i use that word right)?

Comment: @user1375469 You must have tried initializing your object without any constructor type-arguments. Don't forget the type-arguments.

Comment: Okay, I've added default constructors to the symbol struct, and it works now, but I'm confused as to why a call to a default constructor is needed?

Comment: @user1375469 The compiler needs to know how to initialize your structure in case no parameters are give. Otherwise it's values (correct me if I'm wrong) MAY give "unknown results".